# $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which there is an $\alpha >0$ such that for all $a \in A$ and all $b \in B$, $|a-b| \geq \alpha$. Prove that  $m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$.

I can't use Caratheodory because it is in the next chapter. Just properties of outer measure.

Comment: What is your exact definition of $m^\ast$?

Comment: The word here is "precise" yes?

Comment: $$m^*(A) = \text{inf} \{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k) | A \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k \}$$

Answer (score 1):

By general properties of outer measures, $m^\ast (A \cup B) \leq m^\ast (A) + m^\ast (B)$, so that we only have to prove the reverse estimate.

In the case $m^\ast(A\cup B) =\infty$, this is trivial, so assume $m^\ast(A \cup B) < \infty$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and choose a covering $(I_k)_k$ of $A \cup B$ such that

$$
\sum_k \ell(I_k) \leq m^\ast(A \cup B) + \varepsilon. \qquad (\dagger)
$$

Note that we can assume $I_k \cap (A \cup B) \neq \emptyset$ for each $k$ (why?).

Also, we can replace each interval $I_k = [a_k, b_k]$ by a suitable finite union

$$
I_k = \bigcup_{m=1}^{m_k} [a_{k,m}, b_{k,m}]
$$

with $b_{k,m} - a_{k,m} \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{m_k} (b_{k,m} - a_{k,m}) = \ell(I_k)$, without changing $(\dagger)$, i.e. we can assume $\ell(I_k) \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ for all $k$.

Now, let

$$
I_A := \{k \in \Bbb{N} \mid I_k \cap A \neq \emptyset\}, \\
I_B := \{k \in \Bbb{N} \mid I_k \cap B \neq \emptyset\}.
$$

Because of $I_k \cap (A\cup B) \neq \emptyset$ for each $k$, we see $\Bbb{N} = I_A \cup I_B$. Furthermore, $I_A \cap I_B = \emptyset$ follows from your assumption that $|x-y| \geq \alpha$ for all $x \in A$, $y \in B$ together with $\ell(I_k) \leq \alpha/2$ (why?).

Hence,

$$
m^\ast(A) + m^\ast(B) \leq \sum_{k \in I_A} \ell(I_k) + \sum_{k \in I_B} \ell(I_k) = \sum_k \ell(I_k) \leq m^\ast(A \cup B) + \varepsilon.
$$

As $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why we can replace each interval with an interval such that it's length is less than $\frac{\alpha}{2}?$

Comment: @Mathematical: Can you say what is unclear with my explanation? You are given a countable covering of $A\cup B$ with intervals $I_k$ whose length sum up to at most $m^\ast (A\cup B) +\epsilon$. Now, it is easy to see that each interval $I_k$ can be written as a finite union $I_k = I_k^1\cup\dots I_k^{m_k}$ of intervals all of which have length at most $\alpha /2$ which intersect at most at the boundary points (is this the problem?). Then $\ell(I_k) = \sum_m \ell(I_k^m)$, so that if we replace the family $(I_k)$ by the family $(I_k^t)_{k\in \Bbb{N}, 1\leq t \leq m_k}$, this new family works.

Comment: Yeah, it's writing $I_k$ as a finite union of disjoint intervals that intersect at most at the boundary points, but I think I see it now. I was trying to write them as completely disjoint, but allowing the to intersect at boundary points is fine. Also, you used closed sets in your explanation, which I'm sure turns out to be the same thing, I'm just used to outer measure being described as the infimum of measures of open covers.

Comment: @Mathematical: Yeah, so for example if $I_k = [0,5/2]$ and $\alpha =1$, then you would write $I_k = [0,1]\cup [1,2]\cup [2,5/2]$. Nothing magic going on. If the intervals in question are open, it gets slightly more tricky, but then you could allow overlaps of size $\epsilon / (2^k [1+ \alpha / \ell(I_k)])$ (more or less), so that the total measure of overlaps sums to something less than $\epsilon$. Maybe it's easier to first convince yourself that it does not matter whether you use open or closed intervals.